# Как убить функцию в swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Как убить выполняемую функцию?

Опишу проблему: в функции идет загрузка различных видео и если загрузка превышает 15 секунд - я спрашиваю пользователя, продолжить ему или нет, но в этот момент загрузка все так же продолжается. Если да - продолжить загрузку, если нет - убить функцию, как бы прекратить загрузку. Как это реализовать?

```
var count = 0
var timer = Timer()
var activeTask: URLSessionTask!
func startPressed() {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
func counter() {

    count += 1

    print(count)

    if count == 5 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Продолжить загрузку?", message: "Это может занять долгое время ...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Да", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Нет", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

        self.activeTask.cancel()

        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if count > 5 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}

func parse(callback: @escaping (_ text: String, _ images: NSMutableArray, _ countVideoLink: Int, _ countImageLink: Int, _ pathToTheVideoFile: [String], _ sourceLink: String) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    activeTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let response = swiftyJSON["response"].arrayValue


            let countVideoLink = videoLinks.count

                for video in videoLinks {

                    if let videoURL = URL(string: video) {
                        // create your document folder url
                        let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

                        // your destination file url
                        let destination = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(videoURL.lastPathComponent + ".mp4")
                        pathToTheVideoFile.append(String(describing: destination))

                        // check if it exists before downloading it
                        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
                            print("The file already exists at path")
                        } else {
                            //  if the file doesn't exist
                            //  just download the data from your url
                            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: videoURL, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) in
                                // after downloading your data you need to save it to your destination url
                                guard
                                    let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                                    let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("video"),
                                    let location = location, error == nil
                                    else { return }
                                do {
                                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                                    print("file saved")
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }).resume()
                        }
                    }

                    indexVideo += 1
                }


                for link in photoLinks {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let url = NSURL(string: link)

                        if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL) {

                            let img = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

                            let data : NSData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(img!)!)

                            CDataArray.add(data)

                            indexPhoto += 1

                            if indexPhoto == countImageLink && indexVideo == countVideoLink {

                                callback(text, CDataArray, countVideoLink, countImageLink, pathToTheVideoFile, sourceLink!)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    activeTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Вы должны остановить загрузку. Если используете URLSessionTask, то там есть метод cancel (activeTask.cancel()).

Comment: @VitaliEller не могу понять как вызвать метод cancel, если функция уже запустилась и идет, как ее можно прервать? Подскажите верное направление

Comment: Добавил примерное объяснение. Если и это не понятно, то добавьте свой код, там и посмотрим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cоздаем таск: `var activeTask: URLSessionTask?`

Далее начинаем запрос:

```
activeTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
```

// тут выполняется загрузка
    }

И теперь в момент, когда надо закончить `activeTask.cancel()`

Comment: добавил исходный код

Comment: Так выглядит верно, в чем сейчас вопрос?

Comment: Точнее даже так, получается после отмены он не попадает в callback, верно?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо большое)